# Selecting every 100 rows from MySQL witha next button in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to implement this code into a site but I have a few questions. What does the code mean exactly? How does it translate? "end as x" what is it doing here? does anyone have a recommendation as to how to best use it with php? I found this script on PHP and asked the creator but I want to ask the community to see if I get a quicker response.

To better clarify, I am trying to select every hundred rows. I am trying to create a next button that will pull every 100 rows with every click of the next button or arrow. Like a pagination but without the number of the pages.

```
SELECT * FROM storeCoins WHERE intId in (SELECT CASE(intId%100=0) WHEN 1 THEN intId else 0 END AS X FROM storeCoins ORDER BY 'year' ASC
```

I don't understand what the syntax means but would really like to understand this. Seems very efficient. If you can recommend how to best implement this using PHP that would be very helpful. I created a next button that only shows the next id in the database but not the next 100. My biggest interest is in understanding this sql code.

Comment: instead of yelling on people why dont you take out your precious time and read this article and edit the quaetion

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

maybe negative symbls go away

Comment: I thought I joined this platform to engage with other and help each other out? So I asked. No one was yelling. THIS IS YELLING. pointless discussion...

Answer (score 0):

it can be as simple as...

For page 1 use

```
SELECT * FROM storeCoins ORDER BY 'year' ASC limit 0, 100
```

for page 2 us

```
SELECT * FROM storeCoins ORDER BY 'year' ASC limit 99, 100
```

for page 3 us

```
SELECT * FROM storeCoins ORDER BY 'year' ASC limit 199, 100
```

and so on

Comment: You may answer the other questions from the OP (:

Comment: Thanks Rocky, I do know that I can do it this way but I was looking for one script that didn't require me having to create multiple pages. I can us your example in a database column maybe and change based on the row columns being displayed. Guess I was looking for something more like the code below. "SELECT id,catName FROM storeCoins WHERE id > '$id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"